# Moq Unit testing linq queries

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to test a method in my service class layer, it currently gives a null reference error message because I'm using a method in my setup called .GetById but in my service class I'm using a linq query.

My main question is how would I change .GetById to actually test a linq query?

Please let me know if more information is needed

My current unit test method:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task GetCafeByIdAsync_Should_Throw_ArgumentNullException()
    {
        var cafe = new Cafe()
        {
            CafeId = 1,
            Name = "Bellas"
        };

        var mockCafe = new Mock<IRepositoryAsync<Cafe>>();
        mockCafe.Setup(x => x.GetByIdAsync(cafe.CafeId)).ReturnsAsync(cafe); //errors on this line

        
        var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfile());
        }).CreateMapper();

        var cafeService = new CafeService(mockCafe.Object, mapper);
        
        await Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentNullException>(() => cafeService.Get(2));
    }
```

My service class I'm trying to unit test:

```
        public async Task<VersionResponse> Get(int cafeId)
        {
            var cafe = await _context.Cafe.Where(w => w.CafeId== cafeId).ToResponse().FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            
            return new VersionResponse()
            {
                Data = cafe
            };
        }
```

Comment: you do not call any GetById method in your code.

Comment: I'd simply mock  _context.Cafe and let linq to do its work

Comment: Yup I removed it from my service class but in my unit test methods it's called GetById

Comment: how do I mock a context?

Comment: I'd have to mock a db as well?

Comment: You should mock the context the same way you are mocking Repository. You need to then setup expectations for Cafe property so that it will return a collection of Cafe objects.

Comment: You don't need to mock repository if you are not using it in service code.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya but when you are using .setup() I need a method which is not used in my service class. I'm only using linq ?

Comment: `but when you are using .setup() I need a method which is not used in my service class.` what does this mean? You might want to read [this](https://softchris.github.io/pages/dotnet-moq.html#the-api-project). If you have made any changes in the original code, can you  please update the question with latest code and explain the issue you are facing?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya that link doesn't use linq